# APA style: Changing direct quote "drew" to "drawing" -- where to place square brackets?

Tags: quotations, style-manuals, square-brackets

If the original quote uses "drew" and I want to integrate it into my text by changing it to "drawing", which of the following would I write?

> "dr[awing]"

Or

> "[drawing]"

This always confuses me... I can't find anything by Googling.

Comment: You might at least give us the actual example context where you want to do this. Without that I think it will inevitably be closed soon.

Comment: I'd go with the second, on the grounds of aesthetics. If you wanted to replace "it" with "the kitten" you wouldn't write "I love [the k]it[ten] very much" unless you were insanely awkward.